# implementing a chat webapplication

Tags: php, web-applications, push-notification, chat, real-time

I need to develop a web application with a chat feature, and I would like to know if there are any sophisticated ways to create a realtime web-application with a push engine.

I know jQuery, and I can handle to create a chat web-application which, in the client side, check every period for new messages, and show them, but I don't like this solution and I was wondering if there are any better ways to do it.

In my research I discovered the existence [Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/) project, and it looks like what I need, but when I was navigating in their website I found it not very well done and somehow incomplete, so I was wondring if there API is stable enough to be put in a production environment if not are there any other solutions?

Sorry if I made it long, any **help/hint/link/suggestion** would be very welcomed :)

**EDIT**

I would like to specify that I'm working with PHP in the server side

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation in NodeJs.

http://dhotson.tumblr.com/post/271733389/a-simple-chat-server-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

I recently (year 2012) developed an application in ASP.NET MVC3 where I used [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for real-time messaging between server and client. At [their own site](http://signalr.net/), they describe SignalR like this:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

... and they give the following example of what you can use SignalR for:

> SignalR can be used to add any sort of "real-time" web functionality to your ASP.NET application. *While chat is often used as an example*, you can do a whole lot more. Any time a user refreshes a web page to see new data, or the page implements Ajax long polling to retrieve new data, is candidate for using SignalR.

Further, based on my experience, I believe it is very simple to set up, easy to use, and have a good [github page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) with well-written documentation that gets you going in no time. I can highly recommend it :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, indeed SignalR seems to be an interested subject, but I made a mistake in my post forgetting to specify that my web application is based on PHP in the server side, I'll update it right now, but I will consider your recommendation to pass it to my friends who are using .Net technologies